# Angular Modular Routing with '**' no matching route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, custom-error-pages

To have the n each separete sub-module with routes.forchild is a great methode to modulrize the applikation, fine. But how to handle all not matching urls? If I implement into the main (boottrap)   AppRoutingModul    following routes

`const routes: Routes = [     {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},     {         path     : 'home',         component: HomeComponent     },   {path: '**', ErrorComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},`

anytime the the '**' route will excecute unless a correct child rout exist.

If I implement at the last child module.ts such

```
{path: '**', ErrorComponent },
```

t will never works.

The only way seem to have all routes in the common root module, but at least a modularisation is not possible in the smart way (components and rootes in the same folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the apache server
inside the .htaccess file (perl)

The /404 in the ErrorDocument and RewriteRule directives is the URL of your custom error component. You will need to replace this with the actual URL of your component in your Angular app.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404 [L]
```

what it does so far

The RewriteEngine directive is used to turn on Apache's URL rewriting engine, and the RewriteCond and RewriteRule directives are used to redirect all invalid URL requests to the custom error page.

with extra modifications
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle all not matching URLs, you need to place the catch-all route with the path '**' in the main routing module, the one that is bootstrapped in your application. This is because the catch-all route will only be activated if no other route in the application matches the requested URL.

If you place the catch-all route in a child module, it will not be effective, as the child modules only handle the routes within their own scope, and the main routing module is the one that has access to the complete URL.

Lazy rendering is a great tool.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '**', component: ErrorComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'feature1', component: Feature1Component},
  {path: 'feature2', component: Feature2Component},
];
```

loadChildren property in the route configuration is a tool for lazy loading of feature modules.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'feature',
    loadChildren: () => import('./feature/feature.module').then(m => m.FeatureModule)
  },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: In my application I have more than 7 "sub-"module, in which I have the separated routes[] .
So I have to add e.g.7 times
 path: 'featureN',
 loadChildren: () => import('./featureN/featureN.module').then(m => m.FeatureNModule)

Comment: I added this without success:
...
import { BiegebalkenModule } from "./pages/biegebalken/biegebalken.module";
.....
 
  {
      path     : 'home',
      component: HomeComponent
  },
{
  path: 'biegebalken',
  loadChildren: () => (BiegebalkenModule)
},
....
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
....

Comment: @NgModule({
              imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
                useHash: true,
                anchorScrolling: "enabled",
                onSameUrlNavigation: "reload",
                enableTracing: true,
                scrollPositionRestoration: "enabled"
              })],
              exports: [RouterModule]
          })

Answer (score 0):

There is a different, if an Angular Route will not find the path eg. .de/pageDoesNotExist-404 WITHIN the Angular App, then the proposed answer is correct for

```js
  {
    path: 'feature',
    loadChildren: () => import('./feature/feature.module').then(m => m.FeatureModule)
  },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

and correct error page will shown.

But, if the URL DIRECTLY CALL from browser with a wrong path: https://....de/pageDoesNotExist-404

the angular app will not cover the missmatch and the apache server will do the error routine.